# What's the directory/location where the installations from repositories go?

Tags: directory, repository, plugins

I want to install the program ImageJ from the Ubuntu repositories (mainly because it's easier than compiling the code from source), but I need to add a few plugins to the basic installation.

I would like to know where would the program be installed (physically, like the directory path on my computer) so that I can manually add the plugins. Does anybody knows what it is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: After installing a package, you can use `dpkg -L packagename` to find all the directories and files related to that package.

Comment: Thank you very much @G_P! I'll see if I can find the directory for the plugins.

Comment: It probably is, since I almost never use the repositories and place the installations on my personal folder for easy twitching.